# Many leaderboards

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

I am developing a puzzle game and I want to integrate Google Play Game Services for leaderboards. Currently there is a [maximum of 70 leaderboards per game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#multiple_leaderboards). The problem is that eventually my game will have more than 70 puzzles and I would like to track the solving times for every puzzle.

What are my options to have more then 70 leaderboards? Like contacting Google and lifting the limit, or use another reliable service, or even create my own server? Or create multiple games in Google Play Developer console when I hit the limit of 70 leaderboards? Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: @StupidBird not yet. but the only solution is probably to use a 3rd party provider instead of google. once i release my game i will probably try to contact google directly.